# Angular 9 upgrade from 8 - Package '-y' is not a dependency

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am **upgrading** my application from **Angular 8 to 9**. I used the below command.

```
ng update @angular/core@9 @angular/cli@9 -allow-dirty --force
```

I am getting **Package '-y' is not a dependency** **error message**, I don't know what is wrong.

*Attached screenshot for your reference*.

**Screenshot**

[image]

**package.json** file

```
{
  "name": "xxxx",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "build": "npm run env -s && ng build --prod",
    "start": "npm run env -s && ng serve --aot --proxy-config proxy.conf.js",
    "serve:sw": "npm run build -s && npx http-server ./dist -p 4200",
    "lint": "ng lint && stylelint \"src/**/*.scss\" --syntax scss && htmlhint \"src\" --config .htmlhintrc",
    "test": "npm run env -s && ng test",
    "test:ci": "npm run env -s && npm run lint -s && ng test --code-coverage --watch=false",
    "e2e": "npm run env -s && ng e2e",
    "translations:extract": "ngx-translate-extract --input ./src --output ./src/translations/template.json --format=json --clean -sort --marker extract",
    "docs": "hads ./docs -o",
    "env": "ngx-scripts env npm_package_version",
    "prettier": "prettier --write \"./{src,e2e}/**/*.{ts,js,scss}\"",
    "prettier:check": "prettier --list-different \"./{src,e2e}/**/*.{ts,js,scss}\"",
    "postinstall": "npm run prettier -s",
    "precommit": "pretty-quick --staged",
    "generate": "ng generate"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.2",
    "@angular/common": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^8.0.0-beta.27",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^8.2.14",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-webfonts": "^1.0.9",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^3.3.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^10.0.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-common": "^1.2.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^4.2.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^2.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "^3.0.3",
    "angular-archwizard": "^5.0.0",
    "angular-user-idle": "^2.2.2",
    "angular2-notifications": "^2.0.0",
    "angular5-csv": "^0.2.11",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.6",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "highcharts": "^8.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "mat-table-exporter": "^1.2.5",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "0.2.3",
    "ng2-toastr": "^4.1.2",
    "ng6-toastr-notifications": "^1.0.4",
    "ngx-pagination": "^4.1.0",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^8.0.0",
    "ngx-select-dropdown": "^1.2.1",
    "ngx-select-ex": "^3.7.3",
    "ngx-toastr": "^10.1.0",
    "ngx-ui-loader": "^7.2.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.3",
    "save": "^2.4.0",
    "slavede-ng-dual-list-box": "^1.1.5",
    "zone.js": "^0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.24",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.29",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "^8.2.14",
    "@biesbjerg/ngx-translate-extract": "^2.3.4",
    "@ngx-rocket/scripts": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.7",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.2",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.108",
    "@types/node": "^8.10.13",
    "codelyzer": "^4.4.4",
    "hads": "^1.7.0",
    "htmlhint": "^0.10.0",
    "https-proxy-agent": "^2.0.0",
    "husky": "^0.14.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.1.0",
    "karma": "~3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^1.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "prettier": "^1.14.0",
    "pretty-quick": "^1.6.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "rebuild-node-sass": "^1.1.0",
    "stylelint": "~9.6.0",
    "stylelint-config-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "stylelint-config-recommended-scss": "~3.2.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "~18.2.0",
    "stylelint-scss": "~3.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.14.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  },
  "prettier": {
    "singleQuote": true,
    "overrides": [
      {
        "files": "*.scss",
        "options": {
          "singleQuote": false
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

If you need anything other than package.json file, please let me know

Someone, please help me out.

Comment: Might be a typescript error, what version of TS are you using? Also what is your CLI version?

Comment: package.json added

Comment: Sorry, are you following it: https://update.angular.io/?l=2&v=8.2-9.1 ?

Comment: Did you try `--allow-dirty` instead of `-allow-dirty` (two leading dashes)?

Comment: @Patrick, Yes followed exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your command. Instead of `-allow-dirty`, it should be `--allow-dirty` (two leading dashes).

```sh
ng update @angular/core@9 @angular/cli@9 --allow-dirty --force
#                                        ^^
```